# How to create a typed array with all the object keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there anyway to get a typed array with all the object properties?

I was doing something like this:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

const personKeys: Array<keyof Person> = ["name"] // no error here unfortunately
```

The problem with this solution, is that typescript **doesn't constraint me to have all the object keys in the array**, one is enough.

Is there anyway in typescript where I could achieve having an array that would require all the object's keys?